# send an email with python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Receive and send emails in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348392/receive-and-send-emails-in-python)

I tried searching but couldn't find a simple way to send an email.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
from:"Test1@test.com"#email sender
To:"test2@test.com"# my email
content:open('x.txt','r')
```

Everything I've found is complicated really: my project doesn't need so many lines.

Please, I like to learn: leave comments in each code and explain

Comment: guys it's would be ok for me if we use stmp like usernmae='test@test.com' and pass_='test2312'

Answer (score 8):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html) are pretty straitforward:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import smtplib

def prompt(prompt):
    return raw_input(prompt).strip()

fromaddr = prompt("From: ")
toaddrs  = prompt("To: ").split()
print "Enter message, end with ^D (Unix) or ^Z (Windows):"

# Add the From: and To: headers at the start!
msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n"
       % (fromaddr, ", ".join(toaddrs)))
while 1:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not line:
        break
    msg = msg + line

print "Message length is " + repr(len(msg))

server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: `email` is a wrapper for the low-level `smtplib` module that saves you having to e.g. hardcode headers.

Comment: Don't forget to give credit: http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html

Comment: haha, that's amusing.  I knew I had this python code buried somewhere in my homedir, I'd long since forgotten its source.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example, which works for me, using [smtplib](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307142251/https://www.usda.gov/wps/portal/usda/usdahome):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib                           # Brings in the smtp library

smtpServer='smtp.yourdomain.com'         # Set the server - change for your needs
fromAddr='you@yourAddress'               # Set the from address - change for your needs
toAddr='you@yourAddress'                 # Set the to address - change for your needs

# In the lines below the subject and message text get set up
text='''Subject: Python send mail test

Hey!

This is a test of sending email from within Python.  

Yourself!
'''

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer)        # Instantiate server object, making connection
server.set_debuglevel(1)                 # Turn debugging on to get problem messages
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, text)  # sends the message
server.quit()                            # you're done
```

This is code I found a while back at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609222805/http://xahlee.info/perl-python/sending_mail.html) and modified.