# Easiest way to send emails via Python

Tags: python, email, ubuntu, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Receive and send emails in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348392/receive-and-send-emails-in-python)

I've been looking into sending mail with python and found a few different options (setting up my own mailserver, using gmail's smtp, etc) but was wondering if there was some simple way to do it. I am running the python script via wsgi on apache2 on an ubuntu box. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Kinda. He's more interested in incoming and outgoing. I'm just looking into a way to send emails without using gmail (some other smtp server I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great example [here](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example). As you seem to know, you'll just need an smtp server to do the actual sending. That particular step is not dependent on python.

If g-mails smtp server let's you send mail, I'd go that route. When I last set this up (for an svn backup script), I luckily got to use my company's smtp server.

Comment: I was hoping I could get around using gmail as it always says sent from your gmail account but that worked well enough. I used this: http://kutuma.blogspot.com/2007/08/sending-emails-via-gmail-with-python.html