# How do I receive mail using Python?

Tags: python, email

I am trying to make a program on my computer at home that will constantly check a certain gmail address; The purpose being the only email this address receives is from me.

I would just like to be able to

1. Check for mail
2. Download mail (presumably to a string, though a file is acceptable), and
3. Delete the mail from the web server but keep it on my computer.

That is all I need to know right now, however my long term goal is to set up kind of a remote terminal over email, so that wherever I have email I have a certain amount of control over my computer.

Comment: http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: The best way to receive mail in Python is to search.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348392/receive-and-send-emails-in-python

Answer (score 2):

As Gabi points out, you should check out [libgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/). You might also want to check out [twisted python](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). They have some powerful modules for SMTP, POP3, IMAP, and many more that have nothing to do with email.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a program to just process incoming e-mail, take a look at Pythomnic framework: http://www.pythomnic3k.org/