# Python: Using the SendMessage Function [Example from the Google Developers Page]

Tags: python-2.7, gmail-api

I'm trying to understand and use the example on the Google Developers [page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#examples) for using the Gmail API.  The function takes an argument "service", but I am unsure what it expects here.

```
def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
```

Everything else seems self explanatory but I need help on what to provide for the service variable?

The comment given within the example defines "service" as "service: Authorized Gmail API service instance." Which unfortunately still doesn't help me.

I'm not new to Python, but I am new to using APIs.

Comment: You can check the main method of the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_2_install_the_google_client_library). A service is created there.

Answer (score 4):

The argument "service" does get created in the [python quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_2_install_the_google_client_library)

```
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

That service value can be used in the example you listed in your original question.

Answer (score 2):

The docstring of the function gives us a better idea. Found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

```
 def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
   """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
```

If you do not know how get an authorized Gmail API service instance, you can find a pythong quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python).

In short, you have to make a call to the API, and you will receive a client.json file, which contains your authentication that you can use in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I made the call, and I have the client.json file.  Unfortunately, I am new to using the API calls so I'm not entirely sure what to do with the file.   In the meantime, I have this working using smtplib.  But to do this I had to enable less secure connections, which is why I'd like to explore and get the API call working.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136330/where-do-i-get-the-authorized-gmail-api-service-instance-python-gmail-api)