# Gmail - how to use service instance in python?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to use the Gmail history method discussed here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list#examples

As a test, I am trying to figure out how to use the python code given. One of the parameters is: `service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.`
No datatype is given and it is unclear how to pass that in as a parameter.

I was able to download service credentials as a json and think I may be on the right track, but how would I pass in this json to properly utilize the python function that Gmail provides in the docs? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Try to check this [tutorial](http://free-tutorials.org/using-python-to-make-authentication-into-gmail-api/) on how to use python to make authentication into Gmail API. There is a sample code here that you can copy or serve as a guide in you on how to make authentication. You may also check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136330/where-do-i-get-the-authorized-gmail-api-service-instance-python-gmail-api) related to your problem.