# Where do I get the Authorized Gmail API service instance?

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to update labels using Gmail API and php.

I've reviewed the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136330/where-do-i-get-the-authorized-gmail-api-service-instance-python-gmail-api) but it's about python and doesn't make much sense to me.

I'm referring to the code [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/update#try-it).

Specifically, this:

```
    /**
 * Update an existing Label.
 *
 * @param  Google_Service_Gmail $service Authorized Gmail API instance.
 * @param  string $userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param  string $labelId ID of Label to update.
 * @param  string $labelName Updated name.
 * @param  string $labelListVisibility Updated Label list visibility.
 * @param  string $messageListVisibility Updated Message list visibility.
 * @return Google_Service_Gmail_Label updated Label.
 */
function updateLabel($service, $userId, $labelId, $labelName,
  $labelListVisibility, $messageListVisibility) {
  $label = new Google_Service_Gmail_Label();
  $label->setName($labelName);
  $label->setLabelListVisibility($labelListVisibility);
  $label->setMessageListVisibility($messageListVisibility);
  try {
    $label = $service->users_labels->update($userId, $labelId, $label);
    print 'Label with ID: ' . $labelId . ' successfully updated.';
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
  return $label;
}
```

I think I have all the parameters figured out, but where it says,

```
* @param  Google_Service_Gmail $service Authorized Gmail API instance.
```

I don't know what "Authorized Gmail API instance" is referring to.

I'm connected and authenticated with the API (I can list labels), so I'm guessing it's looking for some reference to my connection. But I don't know where to find this or how to express it.

The following code works to list labels (gauth.php):

```
    <?php
session_start();

require_once('settings.php');
require_once('google-login-api.php');

// Google passes a parameter 'code' in the Redirect Url
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    try {
        $gapi = new GoogleLoginApi();

        // Get the access token 
        $data = $gapi->GetAccessToken(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL, CLIENT_SECRET, $_GET['code']);

        // Get user information
        $user_labels = $gapi->ListUserLabels($data['access_token']);

        $labels_array = $user_labels["labels"];

        $i = 0;

        while($i <= count($labels_array)) 
            {
            if($labels_array[$i]['type'] == "user")
                {
                echo $labels_array[$i]['name']." - ".$labels_array[$i]['id'];
                echo'<br />';
                }
            $i++;
            } 


        // Now that the user is logged in you may want to start some session variables
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;

        // You may now want to redirect the user to the home page of your website
        // header('Location: home.php');
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
```

And here's google-login-api.php:

```
class GoogleLoginApi
{
    public function GetAccessToken($client_id, $redirect_uri, $client_secret, $code) {  
        $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';            

        $curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&code='. $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';
        $ch = curl_init();      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);    
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      
        if($http_code != 200) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to receieve access token');

        return $data;
    }

    public function ListUserLabels($access_token) { 
        //$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me';    
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels';       

        $ch = curl_init();      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);     
        if($http_code != 200) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to get user information');

        return $data;
    }
}
```

And settings.php:

```
/* Google App Client Id */
define('CLIENT_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');

/* Google App Client Secret */
define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

/* Google App Redirect Url */
define('CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/xxxxxxxx/gauth/gauth.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

This tripped me up, too! Google seems to just not care about PHP these days, huh? Their documentation really is as bad as people say it is.

```
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

That's what I did to make progress past this hurdle. I *think* that what they mean with their wording is that you have to create a specific service object like above, instead of just using the client object itself? It could be phrased a lot better, or expanded upon.

Good luck! (You'll need it!)

Answer (score -1):

To get the Access token every time just call this function with valid credentials

```
function GetRefreshedAccessToken($client_id, $refresh_token, $client_secret) {  

    $url_token = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';          

    $curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&refresh_token='. $refresh_token . '&grant_type=refresh_token';
    $ch = curl_init();      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_token);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);    
    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);  //print_r($data);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

    if($http_code != 200) 
        throw new Exception('Error : Failed to refresh access token');

    return $data;
}
```