# Send an email in python

Tags: python, email, server

I am trying to send an email. The code I am using is found below:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

email_user = 'email@gmail.com'
email_password = 'password'
email_send = 'receiver@gmail.com'
subject = 'subject'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'Hi there, sending this email from Python!'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

try:
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user, email_password)   
    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()
    print('successfully sent the mail')
except:
    print("failed to send mail")
```

I get an error "failed to send mail" with the error message:

`SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t10sm6451859wra.16 - gsmtp')`

The error occurs on the `server.login()` line, I am not able to login.
I checked other post and it says, it has to do with wrong credentials but my credentials are correct. I have check and double checked.

What could be the problem with this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: The error message contains a link to [gmail support](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials) that suggests that you may have to allow less secure apps. Did you read and try it?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for the help. Problem resolved!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive and send emails in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348392/receive-and-send-emails-in-python)

Comment: This is a duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

Send an email using python is easy, you may have encountered mistakes in your snippet code above and I am lazy to debug your code. But here might be the code you prefer.
The `smtp.gmail.com,465` make your code secure. This snippet of code will send email to recipient through *spam* but lot number of emails you wish to send, will not be blocked by Gmail, you also can use bot to send email through recipient via this snippet of code.
**Send Multiple Recipients**
In the *to* line, just separate recipients by comma
`to = [
'<recipient_email_address1>',
'<recipient_email_address2>',
'<recipient_email_address3>']`

```html
import smtplib

def sendEmailFunc():
    gmail_user = '<your_sender_email_address_here>'  
    gmail_password = '<credential_password_of_above_email>'
    sent_from = gmail_user  
    to = ['<recipient_email_address>']  
    subject = '<write_your_email_subject_here>'  
    body = "<write_your_email_body_here>" 
    email_text = """
    From: %s  
    To: %s  
    Subject: %s
      
    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)
                 
    try:  
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
        server.close()
        print ('====Email Sent Successfully====')
    except:  
        print ('Something went wrong...')
```

**NOTE**
Please be careful with your indentation.
Hope this helpful for you. 
Thank you.